# Reading UID of mifare classic 1k on iOS12

Tags: ios, nfc, mifare

Is it possible to read the UID of a mifare classic 1k tag?

Recently in iOS12, developers now have the ability to build apps that can interact with the built in NFC reader. I was only able to find documentation on [reading NDEF messages,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag_reader_app) but nothing on reading the UID.

In particular my use case is to use the iPad Pro from 2017 (NFC enabled with iOS 12) to read the UID of mifare classic 1k tags.